# iPad Bug using storyboard with uipageviewcontroller and navigation controller

Tags: swift, ipad, uipageviewcontroller, viewdidload

I have a bug in my code that I hope some can help me with.

I have a `UIPageViewController` in my storyboard and I am also using a `UINavigation` Controller.  When my segue is run which connects one view to switch to the `uipageview` the `viewdidload` method gets called on the `uipageviewcontroller` twice.

Weird thing is it only happens on the iPad the same code on the iPhone only gets called once.  Does anyone know why that would happen?

Comment: Could you add here your storyboard image?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been a bug in iOS.  When I updated my OS the problem was fixed.